# Inconveniente con lista con puntero a cabeza y cola

Tags: c

hace nada he entrado a estudiar estructura de datos en lenguaje c y me han dejado un programa algo complicado para lo poco que me han enseñado: se trata de un programa de practica que contiene una lista que contiene puntero a cabeza y cola.

He hecho todo lo que me pide, desde ingresar a la cabeza, como ingresar a la cola y eliminar un nodo por medio de su índice, pero tengo un inconveniente y es respecto a este inciso:

> **Diseña una función que devuelva un “corte” de la lista. Se recibirán dos índices i y j y se devolverá una nueva lista con punteros a cabeza y cola con una copia de los nodos que van del que ocupa la posición i al que ocupa la posición j − 1, ambos incluidos. La lista devuelta tendrá punteros a cabeza y cola**.

Sólo quiero consejos o alguna solución de como poder llevar a cabo este inciso, muestro lo que llevo de código a continuación.

Estructuras:

```
struct Dato
{
    int num;
    struct Dato *sigte;
};

typedef struct Nodo
{
    struct Dato *cabeza;
    struct Dato *cola;
    int longitud;
}ENodo;
```

Prototipos de funciones:

```
int Menu();
ENodo IngresarCabezera(ENodo lista);
ENodo IngresarCola(ENodo lista);
void MostrarLista(ENodo lista);
int EstaVacia(ENodo lista);
void EliminarElemento(ENodo lista,int n);
```

Funciones:

```
ENodo IngresarCola(ENodo lista)
{
   struct Dato *nuevo=(Dato *)malloc(sizeof(Dato));

   if (nuevo!=NULL)
   {
       puts("Ingrese un numero: ");
       scanf("%d",&nuevo->num);
       nuevo->sigte==NULL;

       if (lista.cabeza==NULL)
       {
           lista.cabeza=lista.cola=nuevo;
       }
       else
       {
           lista.cola->sigte=nuevo;
           lista.cola=nuevo;
       }
       
   }
   
}

ENodo IngresarCabezera(ENodo lista)
{
   struct Dato *nuevo=(Dato *)malloc(sizeof(Dato));

   if (nuevo!=NULL)
   {
       puts("Ingrese un numero");
       scanf("%d",&nuevo->num);
       nuevo->sigte=NULL;
   }
   if (lista.cabeza==NULL)
   {
       lista.cabeza=lista.cola=nuevo;
   }
   else
   {
       nuevo->sigte=lista.cabeza;
       lista.cabeza=nuevo;
   }
   lista.longitud++;
   return lista;
}

void MostrarLista(ENodo lista)
{
   Dato *aux;

   for ( aux = lista.cabeza; aux != NULL; aux=aux->sigte)
   {
       printf("%d\t",aux->num);
   }
   
}
int Menu()
{
   int opcion;
   puts("");
   puts("1 - Ingresar cabecera");
   puts("2 - Mostrar nodos");
   puts("3 - Ingresa cola");
   puts("4. Eliminar por medio de indice.");
   puts("5 - Salir");
   scanf("%d", &opcion);
   
   return opcion;
}
int EstaVacia(ENodo* lista )
{
   return lista->cabeza==NULL;
}

void EliminarElemento(ENodo lista, int n)
{
   Dato *aux;
   if (lista.cabeza)
   {
       if (n==0)
       {
           Dato *aux3=lista.cabeza;
           lista.cabeza=lista.cabeza->sigte;
           DestruirNodo(aux3);
       }
       else if(n<lista.longitud)
       {
          Dato *aux2=lista.cabeza;
           int posicion=0;
           while (posicion<(n-1))
           {
               aux2=aux2->sigte;
               posicion++;
           } 
           Dato *eliminado=aux2->sigte;
           aux2->sigte=eliminado->sigte;
           DestruirNodo(eliminado);
       }
   }
}
```

Se que es mucho código, pero he de demostrar de que ya llevo algo avanzado como para que no piensen que solo quiero que hagan mi tarea y también podría de serle de guía a alguien para que me pueda ayudar, por que se me hace que puedo reutilizar una de las cosas que ya llevo hechas, solo que no se como desarrollarme...

Cualquier ayuda es bienvenida, gracias.

Comment: Consejos: La publicación del código completo para review está buena pero me parece más para GitHub (poné un link acá a modo de info extra, si querés). Lo ideal acá es una pregunta concreta, respondible y que otros puedan tener, acompañada de un ejemplo mínimo y funcional (código que podamos copiar, pegar y revisar). Tu pregunta creo que quedaría mejor como ¿cómo obtener un corte de i a j desde una lista enlazada en C? El código no es mucho. Me sorprende no ver una función para insertar nodos, ni la implementación de DestruirNodo, ni main. Más tarde te publico código. Saludos.

Comment: Respecto a la función de insertar nodo, no lo he hecho en una función como tal, aunque si se que es mejor crear la función para después mandarla a llamar, respecto a la implementación DestruirNodo, este se implementa en la función EliminarElemento, dado que solo elimino un nodo por medio de su índice.

Comment: @D4RIO https://github.com/Geno09/Actividad3-EstructuraDatos.git he subido el archivo .cpp a un repositorio de git, espero sea un poco mas fácil visualizar el código.

Comment: ¿Debés trabajar con C o C++?

Comment: Con lenguaje C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

le hice algunos cambios para que sea entendible. Para salirnos del código completo y hacerlo genérico, vamos a decir que `node` es un nodo común y corriente en una lista enlazada, y `st_lista` es un handler para que la lista tenga dos entradas (cabeza y cola). El handler también lleva cuenta de la longitud actual de la lista, para no tener que contar los elementos.

En esas condiciones, y siendo las estructuras como estas:

```
// esta es la estructura de cada nodo
typedef struct struct_node
{
    int num;
    struct struct_node *next;

} node;

// esta estructura es solo para un handler de la lista
typedef struct
{
    node *cabeza;
    node *cola;
    int  longitud;

} st_lista;
```

podemos crear una función que devuelva un “corte” de la lista, que recibe dos índices `i` y `j` y devuelve una **nueva** lista con su handler (con punteros a cabeza y cola) con una copia de los nodos que van del que ocupa la posición `i` al que ocupa la posición `j` (*OJO, acá pedía `j-1`, pero lo cambié deliberadamente porque lo implementé de manera que sea más intuitivo para nuevos lectores*). La función en cuestión puede ser, por ejemplo, así:

```
st_lista *obtener_corte (st_lista l, int i, int j)
{
    if ((i > l.longitud) || (j > l.longitud) || (i > j))

        return NULL;

    else
    {
        // nueva lista
        st_lista *r = (st_lista*) malloc (sizeof (st_lista));
        node *tmp, *tmp_copia;

        // saltear los primeros
        tmp = l.cabeza;
        for (int it = 1; it < i; it++)
        {
            tmp = tmp->next;
        }

        // crear un nodo copiado
        node *copia = (node*) malloc (sizeof (node));
        memcpy ((void*) copia, (void*) tmp, sizeof(node));

        // poner como único nodo de la nueva lista
        r->cabeza = r->cola = copia;

        // nodo a nodo del corte
        tmp_copia = r->cabeza;
        for (int it = i; it < j; it++)
        {
            tmp = tmp->next;

            // crear copias
            copia = (node*) malloc (sizeof (node));
            memcpy ((void*) copia, (void*) tmp, sizeof(node));

            // avance y construcción de la lista copiada
            tmp_copia->next = copia;
            tmp_copia = copia;
        }

        tmp_copia->next = NULL;

        return r;
    }
}
```

Notá que esta función:

- Retorna `NULL` si no se puede seleccionar el corte pedido. Esto lo tenés que tener en cuenta para usarla y lo tenés que poner en la documentación.
- Retorna memoria del montón asignada con `malloc`, y, por lo tanto, se debe liberar.

Sobre el resto de tu implementación había varias cosas que corregir, a saber:

- Una variable no inicializada antes de su uso.
- La lista enlazada creada **no tenía una función para liberar la memoria asignada**.
- En el `switch` faltaba un `break`.
- Por algún motivo, la estructura usada para los nodos se llamaba `struct List` y la usada para handler de la lista se llamaba `SNode`. Parece tonto, pero cuando uno está usando las estructuras puede meter la pata y perder tiempo valioso.
- El archivo era `*.cpp`, pero contenía código **C**. La extensión para **C** es `*.c`.

Me tomé la libertad de hacer un fork de tu repo y llevar todo a como debería ser. Te mandé un pull request en GitHub para que puedas ver todo el proceso. No es que ese resultado sea algo muy pulido. Por ejemplo, no debería usar `scanf` como lo hace, el uso de tipos más acertados como `unsigned int` podría disminuir algunos riesgos, se puede validar la entrada con expresiones regulares antes de usarla, etcétera.